# View to pass data provided in URL not Mapping

Tags: python, django, url, django-views

I have a Django project structure that looks like this:

```
siteDirectory
    -manage.py
    -mySite
        -__init.py
        -settings.py
        -urls.py (1)
        -public
            -__init__.py
            -urls.py (2)
            -app1
                -models.py
                -views.py
                -urls.py (3)
            -app2
            -app3
            -urls.py
```

(Some files have been omitted for brevity).

I have successfully ran my site and my models work as planned. I then went to setup a URL scheme where I could give a URL like this: `localhost/app1/5` where `5` is the ID of a model object. This is similar to the "Writing more Views" section of the Django Tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/). However, when I implement this, I get a 404 error, and my URL pattern is not defined in my file. These are the URL files I have (they match the corresponding file number in the structure)

urls.py (1)

```
from public import urls as public_urls
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Public-facing site
    url(r'', include(public_urls))
]
```

urls.py (2)

```
from app1 import urls as app_one_urls
from app2 import views as app_two_views
from app3 import views as app_three_views

# URLs
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^app1$', include(app_one_urls)),
    url(r'^app2$', app_two_views.main)
    url(r'^app3$', app_three_views.main),
]
```

urls.py (3)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.main, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<someObject_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.someObject, name='someObject'),
]
```

I can successfully access all of my apps, however only the `someObject` GET does not work. What is causing this 404 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have terminating "$" on all the urls in the second file. This means that nothing further in the string will be matched. Remove those.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` from your `urls.py(2)`.That is

```
url(r'^app1/', include(app_one_urls)),
```